# Add npm credentials to Azure

Tags: azure, npm

In my application I host a private npm package. When I'm trying to do a build in my Azure environment I get `npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @*****`. I also got this message locally when I haven't done the `npm login` command. How do I go about login in or making my credentials available on the Azure environment?

I've added a `.npmrc` file to my project and in the build during the `npmAuthenticate` step it says:

> Adding authentication to the .npmrc file at /home/vsts/work/1/s/.npmrc
>
> SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
>
> SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
>
> SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
>
> Adding credentials for a local registry
> [section]Finishing: npmAuthenticate

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I had to create a token on npmjs.org, add that to the variables in the build. In the build proces I create a .npmrc file with that token and now authentication works.

`- script: |
    echo //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$(NPM_TOKEN) > .npmrc
    dir /a
  displayName: 'npm Authentcation'`